# Reordering legend entries with `style_order` in seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In seaborn you can define different hues (`dinner`/`lunch`) and marker styles (smoker / non smoker) for a scatterplot. By default, seaborn orders the legend entries but I want to know how to define a custom ordering, eg. alphabetical ordering for `time` and leave `smoker` as is.

I tried to define a `style_order` as a list of unique values in the `time` and `smoker` columns, but it doesn't come out right:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, 
                x="total_bill", 
                y="tip", 
                hue="time", 
                style="smoker", 
                style_order=tips['time'].unique().tolist()+tips['smoker'].unique().tolist())
```

[image]

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** I can comment out the `style_order` and add:

```
handles, labels = g.get_legend_handles_labels()
#specify order of items in legend
order = [0,2,1,3,4,5]
#add legend to plot
g.legend([handles[idx] for idx in order],[labels[idx] for idx in order])
```

to get what I need:

[image]

but I don't want to have to manually define `order` or change the alignment of the `time` and `smoker` labels. How can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand why you are including the levels of the `hue` variable in the `style_order` you are trying to set?

Answer (score 0):

To reorder the style order you have created, take the current legend and change the order of the handlers and labels to the desired order.

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, 
                x="total_bill", 
                y="tip", 
                hue="time", 
                style="smoker", 
                style_order=tips['time'].unique().tolist()+tips['smoker'].unique().tolist()
                )

handler, label = g.get_legend_handles_labels()
label[1], label[2] = label[2], label[1]
handler[1], handler[2] = handler[2], handler[1]
# print(label)
g.legend(handler, label)
```

[image]